# Constant warning in Windows EventLog from SQLIaaSAgent: GetTempFileStatusFailed

Tags: sql-server, azure-virtual-machine

We are using SQL Server in an Azure VM on Windows.

Every 30 seconds we get eight warnings in the windows application log caused by the SQLIaasAgent Extension. These warnings started to pop up within the last 1-2 months.
The warnings stop popping up when we stop the SQLIaasAgent service.

```
[Warning] GetTempFileStatusFailed: System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
at System.Decimal.ToInt32(Decimal d)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.ServerConfigurationsManagement.Common.StorageHelper.ConvertToSqlTempFileInfo(String[] fileInfo)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.ServerConfigurationsManagement.Common.StorageHelper.GetTempFileStatus(String filename)
```

The version of the service is up to date.
Has anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has confirmed that this problem is casued by the SQLIaaSAgent extension.
The issue is solved by Microsoft and is fixed in version 2.0.100.0 of the SQLIaasAgent extension.

If you experience the problem from the question, please update your extension to a version >= 2.0.100.0

Follow these steps to update the extension:
[repair-extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-agent-extension-manually-register-single-vm?view=azuresql&tabs=bash%2Cazure-cli#repair-extension)